# Calling a function from one javascript file from another

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage that calls a function from one javascript file on page load. This function then needs to call another function from a different javascript file.

Boiled down to its simplest form, it looks like this:

**HTML File**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Website</title>
    <script type="module" src="testing2.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="testing.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="testFunc()">
    <div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript File 1**

```
import { returnTrue } from './testing2.js';

export function testFunc(){
    console.log(returnTrue())
}
```

**JavaScript File 2**

```
export function returnTrue(){
return true;
}
```

Running this through a live server throws the following error though:

*testing.html:12 Uncaught ReferenceError: testFunc is not defined*
*at onload (testing.html:12:27)*

I know it has something to do with the fact that I've turned both the scripts into the type="module in the HTML file, but I need to do that in order to import the one javascript file to the other.

Any help would be beyond appreciated. I know there's a good chance that this has been answered already but I've run through dozens of different answers on the site and none of them resolve the problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an `onload` attribute directly to the `<body>` element doesn't seem a very good practice. Instead, you can add an `eventlistener` for `DOMContentLoaded` event.

**testing.js:**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    testFunc()
});
```

This will be executed when the `document body` and all its dependencies are loaded.

Hope this helps

Comment: You absolute beauty, thank you so much! I can't upvote the answer because my account is too new, but this is perfect.

Comment: Glad I was able to help you :)

Comment: @TomSchwartz - There's not much point in adding a `DOMContentLoaded` handler using code running in a module. By the time the module is running, the DOM is fully loaded. All that waiting for the event accomplishes is waiting for other modules (that this module didn't import) to be finished loading, which is very much an edge case.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, top-level declarations in modules are not globals, but `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers can only reference global functions.

Two solutions for you:

1. Don't use the `load` event. The `load` event happens ***very*** late in the page load sequence, after all dependent resources (including all images) have been loaded. That's usually (though not always) much later than you need it to be. You can probably just add a call to `testFunc();` at the end of `testing2.js` or in an inline `script type="module"` script, since modules are automatically deferred (they aren't executed until the HTML is parsed and the resulting DOM fully built).

   ```
   <script type="module">
   import { testFunc } from "./testing.js";
   testFunc();
   </script>
   ```
2. If you really need to wait for the `load` event, add it via `addEventListener`, either in `testing2.js` or in your own inline module. Here it is as an inline module:

   ```
   <script type="module">
   import { testFunc } from "./testing.js";
   if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        testFunc();
   } else {
        document.body.addEventListener("load", testFunc);
   }
   </script>
   ```

   Note the check on `readyState`, in case the `load` event has already been fired before the module's code was executed.